# Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do not have permissions to make this API call

Tags: php, paypal

I am facing some issue with Paypal payment gateway integration.

My live site transaction are working fine and payment has approved but test mode payment return following error message

> Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do not have permissions to
>   make this API call

I am using follow URL for the send the request on the test or live mode

```
if ($this->test_mode == 1) {

     $this->submiturl = 'https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com';
}
else
{
    $this->submiturl = 'https://payflowpro.paypal.com';
}
```

I have update the Manager account details by following steps

Business Pro sandbox account in your manager account under "Service Settings --> Set Up --> PayPal Sandbox Email address".

Comment: Do you have Pro enabled in your Sandbox account?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solutions:**

1. This error message is a result of an API call that you cannot make due to the account level setting most likely in your manager account; account preferences, transaction settings: [credit max ] [reference transaction] [ect.] man - what kind of request are you sending? Sale, Credit, Referenced Credit or Reference Transaction?

**Comments**

2. The sandbox account does not need to be in the manager side as that
   is just for testing PayPal Express Checkout payments
3. The endpoints are correct for the test/live gateway